# WARN: Cloning resource attributes from prior resource

Tags: rspec, chef-infra

I have the following piece of recipe code

```
# change permissions and group
execute 'set group' do
  command 'sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/conf'
end

%w(/opt/tomcat/conf /opt/tomcat/conf/*).each do |tomcat_directory|
  execute 'set directory permissions' do
    command 'sudo chmod g+rwx ' + tomcat_directory
  end
end
```

When I run `chef exec rspec --color` I see all tests passing but there is also a warning

```
[2017-05-10T21:12:36+05:30] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for execute[set directory permissions] from prior resource
Previous execute[set directory permissions]: C:/Users/AASJD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chefspec20170510-14248-1faza0file_cache_path/cookbooks/tomcat/recipes/installtomcat.rb:25:in `block in from_file'
Current  execute[set directory permissions]:/Users/AASJD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chefspec20170510-14248-1faza0file_cache_path/cookbooks/tomcat/recipes/installtomcat.rb:25:in `block in from_file' 
(CHEF-3694)C:/Users/AASJD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chefspec20170510-14248-1faza0file_cache_path/cookbooks/tomcat/recipes/installtomcat.rb:25:in `block in from_file'.
Please see https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html for further details and information on how to correct this problem. at C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:43:in `call'
```

https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html As per this link the resources should not have same names or the targets should not be the same but they aren't in this case. Then why is this error is coming up?

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the loop over array. The following code fixed the issue

```
%w(/opt/tomcat/conf /opt/tomcat/conf/*).each do |tomcat_directory|
  execute 'sudo chmod g+rwx ' + tomcat_directory
end
```

Comment: From your first code, you could have just interpolated `tomcat_directory` into the resource name: `execute "set #{tomcat_directory} directory permissions" do` would have worked

Comment: The opposite  , due to Duck typing of ruby,  adding strings can lead to strangers behaviors I.e: x + "A" is likely to end up with the decimal ASCII value if A added to x instead of "1A" If x is 1

Comment: And string interpolation avoid a bunch of memory copy and temporary strings object,  there's a bunch of q/a about it on stackoverflow. Specially in chef recipes,  you should  stick with interpolation to avoid problems with the DSL interpreter and some edge cases where it breaks